# How to get rendered node according to active theme?

Tags: 7

In a `hook_entity_postsave()` function in my custom D7 module, I'm doing the following when a node is saved:

```php
$_ = node_view($entity, 'full');   
$html = drupal_render($_);
```

But the renderd HTML seems to miss the active theme's templates. e.g. turning on theme debug, I get

```
 FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * paragraphs-items--field-sections--full.tpl.php
   * paragraphs-items--field-sections.tpl.php
   x paragraphs-items.tpl.php
```

Yet `paragraphs-items--field-sections--full.tpl.php` is defined in the site's active theme (and is used correctly on presentation of normal node pages).

EDIT: I think this may be because the admin theme is active when this code runs? Is there a way to switch that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely because your admin theme is active when you do the render.

There is no straight-forward and easy way to switch the theme in the middle of a request and you will likely run into further problems.

I would consider other options, e.g. creating the nodes markup via a menu callback that uses the frontend theme, either directly in your `hook_entity_postsave` or in a cron job for example.

If you still want to try it by switching themes, this is the way it worked for my now after a bit of tinkering with the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56358189/368479 and borrowing code from [drupal_theme_initialize()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_initialize/7.x).
The most notable change is the clearing of the cache at the end of the switch function. Performance-wise this is awful, but I couldn't make it work without it.

```
/**
 * Switch to or from an alternative theme in the middle of a request.
 *
 * This is useful if you need to render something (like a node) in a different
 * theme without changing the theme of the entire page. An example use case is
 * when you need to render something for a front end user from an admin page.
 *
 * Usage example:
 *     my_module_switch_theme('bartik');
 *     $node = node_load(1);
 *     $renderable = node_view($node);
 *     $rendered = render($renderable);
 *     my_module_switch_theme();
 *
 * @param string|null $to
 *   The name of the theme to switch to. If NULL, it switches back to the
 *   original theme.
 */
function my_module_switch_theme(string $to = NULL) {
  global $theme, $theme_key;

  // Backup the original theme.
  static $original_theme;
  if (empty($original_theme)) {
    $original_theme = $theme;
  }

  // Perform the switch.
  $theme = $to ?? $original_theme;
  $theme_key = $theme;

  // Find all our ancestor themes and put them in an array.
  $themes = list_themes();
  $base_theme = array();
  $ancestor = $theme;
  while ($ancestor && isset($themes[$ancestor]->base_theme)) {
    $ancestor = $themes[$ancestor]->base_theme;
    $base_theme[] = $themes[$ancestor];
  }
  _drupal_theme_initialize($themes[$theme], array_reverse($base_theme));

  // Themes can have alter functions, so reset the drupal_alter() cache.
  drupal_static_reset('drupal_alter');

  // Clear the cache.
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

Note that this might not work if you implement [hook_custom_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x) for the page where the action happens, but if you use the admin theme then I guess that is not the case.

The code above can then be used like in the following example and correctly uses the `node.tpl.php` from the bartik theme instead of the one that the current theme uses, at least in my test setup.

```
my_module_switch_theme('bartik');
$node = node_load(1);
$renderable = node_view($node);
$rendered = render($renderable);
my_module_switch_theme();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't work. I've also tried the fuller version at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476484/623519 too. It's just not picking up the templates from the theme :-(

Comment: @artfulrobot You are right. Also there is no global `$custom_theme` variable. I was mislead by something I saw and didn't verify. I have updated my answer now. I would strongly suggest to do the rendering at a later point if that is possible. Switching the themes during the active request will easily lead to trouble.

Comment: Thanks! it works! I have found a peformance gain: replace `drupal_flush_all_caches()` with `system_rebuild_theme_data();drupal_theme_rebuild();`